# Why is this grep filter slow?

Tags: regex, unix, command-line, grep

I want to get the first two letters in every word in the BSD dict word list, excluding those words that start with only one letter.

Without the one-letter exclusion it runs extremely fast:

```
time cat /usr/share/dict/web2 | cut -c 1-2 | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | uniq -c > /dev/null

real    0m0.227s
user    0m0.375s
sys 0m0.021s
```

grepping on '`..`', however, is painfully slow:

```
time cat /usr/share/dict/web2 | cut -c 1-2 | grep '..' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | uniq -c > /dev/null

real    1m16.319s
user    1m0.694s
sys 0m10.225s
```

What's going on here?

Comment: ʞɔıu, that has to be one of the coolest account names I've ever seen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The problem is the UTF-8 Locale, easy workaround for 100x speedup

---

What's really slow on the Mac is the UTF-8 locale.

Replace `grep ..` with `LC_ALL=C grep ..` then your command will run over 100x faster.

This is probably true of Linux as well, except a given Linux distro is probably more likely to default to the C environment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it is so awful. But I know one quick way to speed it up is to invert your `grep(1)` expression with `-v`, and throw away all one-character lines:

```
$ time cat /usr/share/dict/words | cut -c 1-2 | grep -v '^.$' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | uniq -c > /dev/null

real    0m0.086s
user    0m0.090s
sys  0m0.000s
```

Answer (score 1):

This might run a little better and would also get rid of your cut needing another pipe.

```
cat /usr/share/dict/web2 | egrep -o '^.{2,}' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | uniq -c > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

it might even be faster if you cut down on the use of excessive pipes and useless cat

```
$ awk '{ a[toupper(substr($0,1,2))]++ } END{for(i in a) print i,a[i] }' file
```